# Typescript: Using resizeObserver but getting type error

Tags: typescript

I am trying to use a resizeObserver and in TS, I am getting the following error:

```
Argument of type '(element: ResizeObserverEntry) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ResizeObserverCallback'.
  Types of parameters 'element' and 'entries' are incompatible.
    Type 'ResizeObserverEntry[]' is missing the following properties from type 'ResizeObserverEntry': borderBoxSize, contentBoxSize, contentRect, target
```

my code is:

```
const resizeObserver = new ResizeObserver((element: ResizeObserverEntry) => {

   // do stuff
});
```

I have tried using `ResizeObserverCallback` but getting a similar error as well.  I dont want to have to just revert to using `any`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`new ResizeObserver` expects `ResizeObserverCallback` as a callback type:

```js
interface ResizeObserverCallback {
    (entries: ResizeObserverEntry[], observer: ResizeObserver): void;
}
```

It means that first argument of a callback is an array of `ResizeObserverEntry` and second argument is an `observer: ResizeObserver`.

You don't even need to use explicit types in your callback. TS is able to contextually infer them.

```js
const resizeObserver = new ResizeObserver((entries,observer) => { // ok

  // do stuff
});
```

As you might have noticed, `entries` and `observer` are typed and not `any`